# Who or what is Glohithia

Tags: ancient-history

I listen again and again in Rotting Christ's song *The sign of evil existence* the chorus "Summon Glohithia, appears in snake shape". I know these guys talks about old folklore, like sumerians or so.

Does any one of you has an idea who, or what it is? Googling only gives me references to the song.

Answer (score 5):

I would bet that Glohithia is just a misspelled Glochidia

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glochidia

which are larvae of freshwater mussels. Some of them appear to have a [snake-like shape](http://molluskconservation.org/MC_GALLERY/Gallery11.html).

Comment: Nice find for an obscure spelling error.

Answer (score 3):

I find no historical reference for this term.  I would say made up for the song lyrics.

Let me edit my answer a little. I *did* spend time searching for this term, and found no website, no link to Sumerian, Babylonian, or Demonic mythologies that I tried linking with the term.  No image showing it. No Book referencing it. That is what I meant by finding no reference to this term. (I hope someone does find something, so I can learn where my search failed.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24349)

Comment: Interesting.  I spent about 20 minutes trying multiple searches and was able to find no trace other then the song lyrics, and two individuals using the name for usernames on forums.  Since I could not find a result confirming the existence of Glohithia, I felt an answer confirming the lack of its existance was appropriate?  Is there another way this type of question is answered on these forums?

Comment: That's a much better response after your edit. Perhaps my *close* vote motivated you to expand on your original post? Remember also that just because I voted to close doesn't mean the community will agree with me - that's why we have a vote.

Comment: Yes, its kind of a catch 22, I can't post links or sources to prove something doesn't exist, so my answer was a bit brief.